# Get notify on session expire [Node.js / Express session]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

I'm currently using node.js with express session and i would like to detect / execute a function when a client session expire. (Ex : write in logs that a client session has expire).

Is it possible ?

Comment: I doubt there's anything regularly checking whether any sessions have expired, much more likely is that you'd find out on the *next* request the client made. What's handling your sessions, and did you look into the hooks and middleware it offers?

Comment: Having same issue. I'm not finding any good answers to this problem.